# Calling multiple handles inside ListenAndServe

Tags: go

I want to use multiple handlers inside the `ListenAndServe` method from the `http` package. For example:

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+s.config.Port,
    handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, s.router),
    handlers.CORS()(r.router)
); err != nil {
```

**Problem:**

Everytime I'm getting the following error:

> pkg/server/server.go:30:31: too many arguments in call to 
>   http.ListenAndServe have (string, http.Handler, http.Handler) want
>   (string, http.Handler) pkg/server/server.go:30:113: undefined: r

**Question:**

Now it's not accepting more than 2 arguments, so is there any alternative of doing this?

Comment: Yes, wrap them into a single custom type (struct, slice, doesn't matter as long as it can reference the handlers you want to "combine") and have that type implement the handler interface. And you should also be able to do this `http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, handlers.CORS()(r.router))`.

Comment: It only takes a single handler. So you need to wrap everything you want to do in a single handler function. Or alternatively you can use a router library like mux or chi that will make these things easier.

Comment: Google "http middleware".

Comment: justinas/alice does this. Middleware is also built into gorilla/mux now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListenAndServe` only takes a single `http.Handler`.

The simplest way to do this without bringing in a library is to build a `http.Handler` that encompasses both:

```
func simpleChain(hs ...http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    for _, h := range hs {
      h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
  })
}
```

This has some problems though if any of the handlers want to do something to the `Request.Body` or write to the `ResponseWriter`.

For example, you might want a handler to check if the request has permission and then prevent the other handlers from getting invoked. This implies that the `ResponseWriter`'s status code needs to be checked. I would say bring in a library at this point.